# How many faces does this object have?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, geometry

The object came with a few clues to help you figure it out.

> I can be viewed on paper
>   I cannot be viewed in reality by your kind
>   I am made up of what your mind can truly comprehend
>   I resemble a shape many learn first in primary

It's freakishly easy if you think in a specific way.

**BONUS (for people who don't mind risking not being first for more quality):**

> *How many edges and vertices does it have, and what does it look like?*

Comment: Um... Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: A down-vote seems unwarranted until you at least know the answer.

Comment: You have a honking big typo, or at the least extraordinarily awkward grammar, at the very beginning of your title; that's something that often inspires people to see your question as poor quality and thus downvote. (Don't assume that I've done so just because I'm making this comment -- I may have voted up, down, or not at all.)

Comment: @Josh Wow, never even noticed that!

Comment: @Josh "How's my faces". That was most likely auto correct.

Comment: This question has many possible answers

Comment: @warspyking I downvoted because there are so many possible answers that fit all the clues, and not enough information to determine which one you happen to be thinking of. For example, a Klein bottle. Or just an n-dimensional tesseract for n>4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A [tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) (a 4-dimensional analog of the cube). You can see the projection of a tesseract. "Our kind" is three-dimensional, so we cannot see it. It is made of cubes which we can comprehend. It resembles a square which we learn in primary (it is actually a generalization).
> A really cool [gif](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/8-cell-simple.gif) of a tesseract.
> 24 faces
> 32 edges
> 16 vertices

Comment: Normally, it is projected into a figure that resembles an octogon.

Comment: @Victor I really like this [projection](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/8-cell-simple.gif)

Comment: This was one of the first things that came to mind based on the first two lines (and having recently watched Interstellar). This would have been my second guess. +1 from me.

Comment: Nice! :D I added the bonus if you'd like to include that?

Comment: @warspyking Done :)

Comment: Projections of 3D objects can be viewed on paper, but a tesseract is 4-dimensional. Thus it *cannot* be viewed on paper.

Comment: @MackTuesday Every 1+ dimensional object can be viewed on paper, i.e. it can be projected in 2D, regardless of its dimensionality. Have a look at [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Hypercube.svg), [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Schlegel_wireframe_8-cell.png) and [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Graphs)

Comment: @dmg Strictly speaking, a mathematical projection is possible, but try viewing a cube on a 1-dimensional substrate. That's equivalent to what you propose. The images you link are of 3D projections of tesseracts. They don't hint at the full geometry. I mean, maybe I'm splitting hairs, but I feel it's more than a trifle.

Comment: @MackTuesday Technically, any non-3D object is hard to comprehend for any human being - we live in 3D. Some fancy adding time as a dimension, although watching a 3D cube for 3 hours, hardly makes it any different. On the other hand, a 3D convex polytope can be fully defined through 2D using 3 projections. I imagine there is a number of 2D projections that can define a 4D convex polytope. TL;DR: dimensions are cool.

Answer (score 17):

The number of faces is:

> Zero

The object is a:

> A point

Line 1: `I can be viewed on paper`

> A point can be viewed on paper.

Line 2: `I cannot be viewed in reality by your kind`

> A point, a dimension-less object, cannot be seen in the real world.

Line 3: `I am made up of what your mind can truly comprehend`

> There is a philosophy tag. As we learn more, we realize how little we actually know. There is no real way to know that we truly comprehend something as technology and science change our perspectives as time advances. Therefore, we can say that there is nothing we truly comprehend. A point can be considered made up of nothing.

Line 4: `I resemble a shape many learn first in primary`

> A point resembles a circle on paper.

Comment: "The mind can truly comprehend nothing"? Really?

Comment: LOL I can officially comprehend how hilarious this answer is with that comment about how mind not comprehending anything. -1 D:

Comment: @randal'thor There is a philosophy tag. As we learn more, we realize how little we actually know. There is no real way to know that we truly comprehend something as technology and science change our perspectives as time advances.

Comment: @jliv902 - Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were saying the mind can comprehend the concept of nothing! That makes it even funnier, I guess...

Comment: @jliv902 You deserve a +1!

Comment: @dmg: +1 from me, now I understand what he's saying!

Comment: Oh that's what he meant! I'll edit to make that clearer but this still wasn't right.

Comment: I undone the edit I made because it was still confusing. Eh, it don't matter.

Comment: @warspyking I edited it after you. Even though it doesn't really matter (since it's wrong), I hope my intentions are more clear now.

Comment: @warspyking What's so hilarious about the idea that we can't comprehend anything? Our entire understanding of comprehension assumes we can comprehend it. Any attempt to prove we can truly comprehend something will inevitably [beg the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question). We can't prove we comprehend things because in order to do so we have to first comprehend how to prove things, which implies we can comprehend something.

Comment: You _truly_ can understand nothing.  I'd say @randal'thor made a point.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

Probably not the intended answer, but

> the [real projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane)

seems to work. It "can be viewed on paper" (see the picture at the top of the link I provided), but "cannot be viewed in reality by your kind" (i.e. by 3D beings) since it cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. It can be seen as being made up of lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which "your mind can truly comprehend". And it looks like JontheMon's answer (again see the picture at the top of the link)!

Comment: I few the answers are inching towards what the solution really is.

Comment: @warspyking - Is it some kind of geometric entity then?

Comment: I refuse to give away too much lol.

Answer (score 2):

Edges and vertices:

> 16 vertices
>  
>  32 edges
>  
>  24 square faces
>  
>  8 cubic cells
>  
>  In 2D, frequently projected as an octogon.

Answer (score 1):

> Well, I'd say it's a square, so 1 face. However, I think that you could view it, just not from the side; unless it's just the boundary of a square. For the 3rd clue, squares are made up of lines, which are made up of points, and points are hard to imagine.

Comment: "I resemble a shape many learn first in primary" if you said square because of this, I said it **resembles** a shape, not that it is a shape.

Answer (score 1):

It is:

> **photons**
>  
>  Light particles/waves that are reflected by a white paper.
>  
>  Their quantum nature can't be really comprehended by our minds. But at the same time, light is all that we see.
>  
>  Their wave resembles sinuidal waves. Although people normally do not know what a sinuidal wave is in the primary, every small kid know their shapes and frequently draws them even without knowing their exact name nor the mathematics behind. If light is considered a particle, then photons are aproximated to spheres, which every small kid knows about.
>  
>  How many faces? This can't really be determined. :)

Comment: It's tagged maths, not physics...

Comment: @rand Just explained why your answer is wrong. Interesting answer noneoftheless.

Comment: Also take a look at it's other tag. Could serve as a hint. (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy)

Answer (score 0):

# of faces:

> 1

---

> The object is any two-dimensional object. 
>  **I can be viewed on paper** 
>  You can view a two-dimensional object on paper. 
>  **I cannot be viewed in reality by your kind** 
>  Our universe is defined in three spatial dimensions. No two-dimensional object can be viewed in reality by us; even a drawing on paper has a thickness, however small, and is never two-dimensional. 
>  **I am made up of what your mind can truly comprehend** 
>  We can comprehend two-dimensional objects pretty easily. 
>  **I resemble a shape many learn first in primary** 
>  Most people learn two-dimensional shapes in primary school. 
>  **How many edges and vertices does it have, and what does it look like?** 
>  Any natural number of edges, any natural number of vertices. It looks like whatever you want a two-dimensional object to look like.